# How to rename the model in DBT During the DBT run

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I need to rename the model name of the DBT during the excuion
ther is a config alias property in DBt but it is not rename in a dynamic way for example if we build a macro to do that rename and used it in config alias  It give erro of undefind name

using macro but did not work as expected with config alias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what I did for the same issue , created macro that execute the alter view rename

{% macro alter_view_name(filter1,filter2,alt_name) %}

```
USE SCHEMA SVS_PSO ;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
    DECLARE
    CustomName    STRING;
    QUERY        STRING;
    BEGIN
    CustomName:= ( select '{{ alt_name }}'||'_'||to_char(max(DATA_CREATE_DT),'yyyymmdd')  
        from {{ ref('yourtable')}}
        where col1 ilike '%{{ filter1 }}%' and col2 ilike  '%{{ filter2 }}%' );
    QUERY:= REPLACE(
            'drop View if exists <cust_name> ;'
            ,'<cust_name>', :CustomName);    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY;     
    QUERY:= REPLACE(
            'alter View if exists {{ this }} rename to <cust_name> ;'
            ,'<cust_name>', :CustomName);    
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY;  
    RETURN :QUERY;
    END;
   $$;
```

{% endmacro %}

then I added this macro as post_hook at the desired view:

```
{{ config ( materialized='view',
    post_hook = [" {{ alter_view_name('filter1','filter2','alternative_name') }}"]) 
}}
```

hope this be helpful